# Having trouble with config step

Tags: 22.04, configure

I'm new to Linux and trying to install Winapps. However, the guide makes significant assumptions that I'm experienced in Linux.

I'm currently stuck on [step 3 of the guide](https://github.com/Fmstrat/winapps). It says to make a config file. I used this command

`sudo nano ~/.config/winapps/winapps.conf`

However, it says *No such file or directory* when I try to save it. I'm not sure how to find the proper directory.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details; which can influence the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create the directory.
Open a terminal and enter the commands

```
cd ~/.config
mkdir winapps
```

Now create the configuration file (you don't need sudo, since it is in the home directory),

```
nano ~/.config/winapps/winapps.conf
```

After you are done writing the contents, press ctrl+x to save and exit.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to successfully do it. But now I'm stuck at step 4. Yikes. This is becoming advanced stuff

Comment: You can accept my answer if that works for you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow For step 4, go to the `bin` folder (must be something you downloaded using git) in the terminal, and then run `winapps check`, after that you are supposed to run `./installer.sh`, according to the readme, but I really don't know anything about winapps.